# Formatting numbers in a mathematical expression from String values in java

Tags: java, string, formatting

I know how to set thousands separator for numbers but i need to display numbers with thousands separator in mathematical expression from `String` values.

Basically, I want these results:

`"123456 + 36514"` becomes `"123,456 + 36,514"`

`"12345678 + 36542 * 69541 / 987654"` becomes `"12,345,678 + 36,542 * 69,541 / 987,654"`

and ...

Comment: @aribeiro I think regex can help me, but i don't understand regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to insert comma after a digit that is followed by an exact number of 3-digit blocks, so:

```
(?<=\d)         Positive lookbehind: Match a digit
(?=             Positive lookahead:
   (?:\d{3})+     One or more sequences of 3 digits
   \b             Word-boundary, i.e. end of digit sequence
)
```

That will match the empty spaces where you want commas, so do a `replaceAll()`:

```java
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(?=(?:\\d{3})+\\b)", ",");
```

See [regex101 for demo](https://regex101.com/r/aF5jR6/1).

Comment: Nice regex thanks ! Any tips on adapting this to not match after the decimal separator?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you an algorithm rather giving the code:

```
Loop: String of repression one character at a time
{
  If the current char is 0 to 9 append to tempNumber string
  else
     {
      //by the time you reach this line the number is in the tempNumber string

      Format the number stored in tempNumber // java.text.NumberFormat
      append the formatted number in targetExpression string
      append the current char to the targetExpression string
}

}
```